# Save some search information between two routings

Tags: angularjs

I have a routing

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
    when("/questions", {controller:"Questions", templateUrl: "questions.html"}).
    when("/objections", {controller: "Objections", templateUrl: "objections.html"}).
    when("/objections/:oId", {controller: "Objections", templateUrl: "objections.html"}).
    when("/persons", {controller: "Persons", templateUrl: "persons.html"}).
    when("/persons/:pId", {controller: "Persons", templateUrl: "persons.html"}).
    when("/questions/:qId", {controller: "Questions", templateUrl: "questions.html"}).
    otherwise({redirectTo : "/persons"});
})
```

and the one template for /objectionsand /objections/:pId

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="objections.html">
<div class="stroke">
<label>Поиск: <input class="border" type="text" ng-model="search.text"></label>
<ul class="objections-objections left_column">
    <li class="border" ng-repeat="objection in objections | filter:search">
        <a href="#/objections/{{objection.id}}">
            {{objection.text}}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="right_column">
    <p class="header"></p>
    <p class="text">
        <span>ID возражения: {{objection.id}}</span>
        <br>
        <textarea class="border" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" ng-model="objection.text"></textarea>
    </p>
    <ul class="questions-objections" ng-show="objection.questions.length">
        <span>Список вопросов</span>
        <li class="border" ng-repeat="question in objection.questions">
            <a href="#/questions/{{question.id}}">{{question.text}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p class="footer">
        <button ng-click="add()">Добавить</button>
        <a href="" ng-click="delete(objection)">Удалить</a>
        <a href="" class="save" ng-click="save()">Сохранить</a>
        <a href="" class="close" ng-click="cancel()">Закрыть</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

so when i input text into search field and have sorted list items then i click to the one of items and see sleared seearch field

how should i reqrite my code that search.text directive won't be reset between this routing?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to persist objects when view change in angular.

- You could define you your search criteria on $rootScope (can be injected into any controller), such as $rootScope.searchCriteria={term:null}; and then bind to this property in you templates. You can directly use `ng-model="searchCriteria.term"`
- You can define the property on the parent controller of ng-view if you have one. Such as

> ```
> <div ng-controller="rootController">
>    <ng-view/>
> </div>
> ```

- You can create a service or define a `value` during module configuration. Since these are singleton in nature, where ever you will inject this service you would get the search criteria object.

`myapp.value("searchCriteria",{term:null});`

```
appRoot.controller("Questions",
        ["$scope", "searchCriteria",
            function ($scope, searchCriteria ) {
```

See module documentation [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module)